# How to develop a Google Gadget compatible server

Tags: widget, igoogle, google-widget, apache-shindig

I am going to develop a Google Gadget container site, that will be able to host OpenSocial compatible widgets (that I believe are Google gadgets, too, right?). Do you have any guidance where to start?

I know that the good start is the [iGoogle Developer Home](http://code.google.com/apis/igoogle/) site and that framework what I would like exists - [Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/overview.html), but is little clumsy. Tutorial links do not work, for start. Do you think it would be wise to use Shindig? Maybe just for a start and then develop any customizations, if needed? Or would be wiser to start from scratch?

So where to start? Do you have any advices, tips or other useful resources to get on faster with this topic?

I guess I can start with [Compliance - Gadget Server](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/spec.html#compliance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shindig is the recommended way and the best way that a lot of people get started.  I have seen a port of Shindig that runs on the app engine, but can no longer find the solution.

As for the tutorial links not working, they work fine for me.  It must be noted that a lot of the link point to your localhost which mean you have to have the gadget server running.